# Показать окно BA авторизации в QWebEngineView

Tags: qt5, pyqt5, qwebengine

Как через QWebEngineView (что уже находится на форме) реализовать возможность авторизации через HTML Basic Auth используя при этом PyQt5?

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы делаете и что у вас не получается и опубликуйте пример демонстрирующий вашу проблему.

Comment: Проблема в том, что при открытии страницы, где используется http-авторизация (когда браузер показывает стандартный диалог авторизации), WebEngineView-виджет показывает "ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED". Это, собственно, вся проблема.